# finding the max date/time for a corresponding value

Tags: excel

I'm trying to find the last time stamp associated with a route-code. The end goal is to use the last time stamp to show when it was completed.

The two column names are "Route_Code" and "time_finished"

I assume the formula would require a combination of 'max', 'and', & 'vlookup' but I can't wrap my noggin around it. I know that a clunky workaround would be to combine the two fields into one and get the max that way, but I'm hoping there's a cleaner way.

Answer (score 0):

What you're after is called MaxIFs. It's available for Excel in Office 365, 2019, web and mobile, but not in Excel 2016 or earlier.

With a Route code in cell A2, you can find the last time stamp like this

```
=maxifs(TimeFinishedRange,RouteCodeRange,A2)
```

If you don't have access to MaxIFs, you can use an array formula like this

```
=max(if(RouteCodeRange=A2,TimeFinishedRange))
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl + Shift + Enter (unless you have the new Dynamic Array version of Excel).